# servlet not sending response via angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servlets

I am trying to run the code that's in this [website](http://ng-angular-js.blogspot.gr/2015/01/reading-data-from-servlet-via-angular.html) but I am not getting the result I am supposed to. I have developed the project on Eclipse and I have an html page on the web content folder and the servlet named "AtpPlayers" under /src/AngularGET folder. I believe that I'm not inserting the right urls.
 Could you help me please ?

Here is the code for the servlet AtpPlayers.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");  
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {         
out.println("[{\"name\": \"Nadal, Rafael (ESP)\", \"email\": \"nadalrafael@gmail.com\", \"rank\": \"1\"},"
+ "{\"name\": \"Djokovic, Novak (SRB)\", \"email\": \"djokovicnovak@gmail.com\", \"rank\": \"2\"},"
+ "{\"name\": \"Federer, Roger (SUI)\", \"email\": \"federerroger@gmail.com\", \"rank\": \"3\"},"
+ "{\"name\": \"Wawrinka, Stan (SUI)\", \"email\": \"wawrinkastan@gmail.com\", \"rank\": \"4\"},"
+ "{\"name\": \"Ferrer, David (ESP)\", \"email\": \"ferrerdavid@gmail.com\", \"rank\": \"5\"}]");
}
```

}

and the html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>             
<title></title>         
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">               
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">           
    angular.module('ATP_PLAYERS', [])            
    .controller('atpController', function ($scope, $http) {               
    $http.get('/AngularGET/AtpPlayers').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                 
    $scope.atp = data;              
    });          
    });         
    </script>         
</head>  
   
<body data-ng-app="ATP_PLAYERS">           
    <div data-ng-controller="atpController">             
    <h5>Loading ATP players from a Servlet</h5>             
    <table>                 
    <thead>                     
    <tr>                         
    <th>Rank</th>                         
    <th>Name</th>                         
    <th>E-mail</th>                     
    </tr>                 
    </thead>                 
    <tbody>                     
       
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in atp">                         
    <td>{{item.rank}}</td>                                     
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>                         
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>                     
    </tr>                 
    </tbody>             
       
    </table>         
    </div>                   
    
    </body> </html>
```

Comment: Please, add the code to your question to make sure that your question will have a meaning even if the target page will no longer exist.

Comment: Is doGet executed? Do you get any errors?

Comment: nope I don't get any errors. The html page loads and it shows the table format but the names won't show up

Comment: Then you should answer your question, explaining the nature of the issue and how you solved it. It might help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

found it ! instead of $http.get('/AngularGET/AtpPlayers') I had to put $http.get('AtpPlayers')

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>             
<title></title>         
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">               
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">           
    angular.module('ATP_PLAYERS', [])            
    .controller('atpController', function ($scope, $http) {               
    $http.get('/AngularGET/AtpPlayers').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                 
    $scope.atp = data;              
    });          
    });         
    </script>         
</head>  
   
<body data-ng-app="ATP_PLAYERS">           
    <div data-ng-controller="atpController">             
    <h5>Loading ATP players from a Servlet</h5>             
    <table>                 
    <thead>                     
    <tr>                         
    <th>Rank</th>                         
    <th>Name</th>                         
    <th>E-mail</th>                     
    </tr>                 
    </thead>                 
    <tbody>                     
       
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in atp">                         
    <td>{{item.rank}}</td>                                     
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>                         
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>                     
    </tr>                 
    </tbody>             
       
    </table>         
    </div>                   
    
    </body> </html>
```